# Check if a text contains HTML-style tags

Tags: java, html, regex, string

First of all **yes I am aware that it's not advisable to use regex to parse HTML**, that's not the purpose of the question.

The thing is, I have some text which may contain HTML style tags like this:

```
<random>
<li>Hi nice to see you!</li>
<li>Hi it's great to see you!</li>
<li>Hi how are you?</li>
<li>Hi! <set foo="bar">I can</set> really feel your smile today.</li>
<li>Hi! It's delightful <sr /> to see you.</li>
</random>
```

What I want to do is to check if the given text contains (just contains) one of more of the tags. I have tried something like this but for the text above it keeps returning false.

```
String regex ="<(?:\"[^\"]*\"['\"]*|'[^']*'['\"]*|[^'\">])+>"; //http://stackoverflow.com/a/1736801
boolean p = Pattern.compile(categoryToUpdate.getTemplate()).matcher(regex).find();
```

Thanks in advance and sorry if it's a silly question :(.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-html-tag-with-regular-expression/

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052052/how-to-find-if-string-contains-html-data

Comment: Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458876/check-if-a-string-is-html-or-not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458876/check-if-a-string-is-html-or-not)

Comment: Change `Pattern.compile(categoryToUpdate.getTemplate()).matcher(regex)` to `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(categoryToUpdate.getTemplate())`.

Comment: As saka1029 has mentioned, the regex and input sequence are swapped. Javadocs: `Pattern java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(String regex)` and `Matcher java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(CharSequence input)`