# Regular Expression to check if a string has HTML code

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

can some one give me the Regular Expression that can check if a given string has any `HTML` code in it, and coming to think of it I would be bothered with `<a  href="something">something</a>` exactly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate that a string doesn't contain HTML using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204646/how-to-validate-that-a-string-doesnt-contain-html-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like this

```
var pattern:RegExp = /<a\s.*?<\/a>/;
var index = str.search(pattern);
if (index != -1) // we have a match
```

Comment: Note also that the following tool is invaluable when working with regex in flash: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/desktop/ + http://gskinner.com/RegExr/.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by "I would be bothered" that it is enough for you if the regex can detect anchor tags, then

```
if (/<a\s.*<\/a>/i.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
}
```

should suffice. This return True if an anchor tag can be matched anywhere in the string.