# How to check if string contents have any HTML in it?

Tags: php, html, regex, xhtml

How can I check if PHP string contents contain any HTML contents?

I'm not good with Regular Expressions so I would like to have a function named "`is_html`" to check this. :) thank you!

Comment: what do you mean "html content"?

Comment: quick google search turned up http://preprocess.me/comment/91

Comment: HTML tags, specific HTML characters like <, >, ", ', =

Comment: What should the `is_html()` function return for the following strings: (1) `"I think that 12<20."`  (2) `"#*D<#(@>"` (3) `"this=that"` (4) `"hello<there>bob"`

Comment: I thought the link i posted was cleaver ehh

Comment: *Why* do you want to know this and how big of a problem are false positives in your use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate that a string doesn't contain HTML using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204646/how-to-validate-that-a-string-doesnt-contain-html-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to test if a string contains a `"<something>"`, (which is lazy but can work for you), you can try something like that :

```
function is_html($string)
{
  return preg_match("/<[^<]+>/",$string,$m) != 0;
}
```

Comment: You know of anyway to represent exactly this expression without a regex? I'm using the same expression, and curious of the difference of regex vs. non-regex.

Comment: Simple, classy, nice hack, I like.

Comment: @IanWood - not really. Take for example `I <3 PHP` - if checking for html using strip_tgs like this `strlen(strip_tags($string)) !== strlen($string)`, it will incorrectly determine that it contains html, when in fact it doesn't. I'm not saying that this answer is the best way to determine if the string contains html, but it is definitely not overkill.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of using regex (like the other suggestions here) I use the following method:

```
    function isHtml($string)
    {
        if ( $string != strip_tags($string) )
        {
            return true; // Contains HTML
        }
        return false; // Does not contain HTML
    }
```

Here I use a PHP function [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove any HTML from the string. It then compares the strings and if they do not match HTML tags were present.

Comment: `strlen` is not necessary there.

Comment: Good point @Red. I've removed `strlen` from the code, even though minimal it saves another process. Thanks for the constructive feedback.

Comment: The function never returns false

Comment: @paulo62 I check whether the method returns `true`.  One can easily put an else if required.  I've updated the it though...

Comment: `strip_tags` is way too agressive in most instances. The string `the value is <4` will return true in your case here.

Comment: `strip_tags` is also bad if you content contain this pattern `<<XXX>>`. e.g. `<<my purpose is to break stuff>>` would be container a tag by `strip_tags`

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer will consider a string containing <something> as HTML which, obviously, it is not.

I use the following, which may or may not be a better idea.  (Comments appreciated.)

```
function isHTML( $str ) { return preg_match( "/\/[a-z]*>/i", $str ) != 0; }
```

This looks for any string containing /> with zero or more letters between the slash and closing bracket.

The above function returns:

```
<something>             is NOT HTML
<b>foo</b>              is HTML
<B>foo</B>              is HTML
<b>foo<b>               is NOT HTML
<input />               is HTML
```

Comment: I'd probably use a `+` there because `</>` isn't HTML. Otherwise, very cool concept!

Comment: @gooli - with a `+` , it wont match `<input />`

Comment: The main problem I see with this regex is it won't match simple <br>, which could be the only tag in a comment in html.

Answer (score 10):

probably the easiest way would be something like:

```
<?php

function hasTags( $str )
{
    return !(strcmp( $str, strip_tags($str ) ) == 0);
}

$str1 = '<p>something with <a href="/some/url">html</a> in.';
$str2 = 'a string.';

var_dump( hasTags( $str1 ) ); // true - has tags.
var_dump( hasTags( $str2 ) ); // false - no tags.
```

Comment: This causes false flags. Take the string for example `I <3 PHP`. This function would determine that tags do exist, when they don't.

Comment: Hmmm, but will scrcmp error on utf-8 text, like many string functions do?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with

```
function isHtml($string){
     preg_match("/<\/?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>/",$string, $matches);
     if(count($matches)==0){
        return FALSE;
      }else{
         return TRUE;
      }
}
```

You just pass a string and check if it returns true or false. As simple as that.

Answer (score -2):

That depends on what you define to be html contents.

The most straightforward thing is to test if the string contains the html tag which can be done with the regex

```
<html.*>
```

In php the test will be

```
if (preg_match('/<html.*>/', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

If you want to see you have valid html it's better to use a html parser.

Comment: I mean if I have any HTML tags containg chars <>, =, and quotes of anykind!

Comment: Hm, the answer above will test if the html tag is present