# Bubble a failed request validation to a controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I don't want to disable validation, however it would be great to display a message to a user. Whilst I think it is highly unlikely that a user will ever have a legitimate need to include &# in a text field, I can see someone typing in a free text field something starting with a <.

Is there a way to detect that a validation exception would be thrown and instead display it as a validation message?

Comment: You could use `[ValidateInput(false)]` on your action and then html encode the input in your controller OR view using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()`.  This way you don't have to worry about validating input.

Comment: @Oliver Thanks, but this is not practical. We have a very large application with many screens and I do not want to do this for each individual method.

Comment: Ok, in that case there are some good suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204646/how-to-validate-that-a-string-doesnt-contain-html-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I resolved this issue:

1. Create a validation rule, say `potentiallyDangerousRequestRule`:

   ```
   var potentiallyDangerousRequestRegex = /[<>]|&#/, // <, >, &#
       potentiallyDangerousRequestErrorMessage = 'The error message';

   $.validator.addMethod('potentiallyDangerousRequestRule', function (value) {
       if (value == '')
           return true;
       return !potentiallyDangerousRequestRegex.test(value);
   }, potentiallyDangerousRequestErrorMessage);

   $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('potentiallyDangerousRequestRule');
   ```
2. Call `validate` method on the `form` element you want to validate:

   ```
   $('form').validate({errorClass: 'input-validation-error'});
   ```
3. Add the rule to elements, for instance all text inputs and textareas:

   ```
   $('input:text, textarea').each(function () {
       $(this).rules('add', { potentiallyDangerousRequestRule: true });
   });
   ```

Make sure you call `validate` method on the form before applying the rule.